# Passing a vector of smart pointers of derived objects - what is the best solution?

Tags: c++, boost, parameter-passing

I'm using boost smart pointers of two classes

```
class Foo{
};

class Derived : public Foo{
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Derived> DerivedPtr;
```

And I keep a vector of my objects as

```
std::vector<DerivedPtr> myVec;
```

which I want to use in a method requesting a vector of the base class smart pointers.

```
Method( std::vector<FooPtr> input ){
... }
```

Using the vector directly, gives an error on compiling.

> `cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<DerivedPtr,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<FooPtr, std::allocator<_Ty>>'`

So my current *solution* is to first 'down-cast' my vector into a new vector of the base class pointers before passing it on:

```
std::vector<FooPtr> downCastVec;
for ( auto & iter : myVec )
    downCastVec.push_back( iter );

Method( downCastVec );
```

This works, but my actual question is:

**Is there a better/more elegant way to deal with this problem?**

Comment: Use `using` instead of `typedef`

Comment: Can you make the function template to avoid copy ?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier why?

Comment: It is not an answer to the question, but it is an advice since `using` is preferred as `typedef` in cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the `std::vector` constructor overload that takes two iterators, to construct a temporary:

```
 Method( {myVec.begin(), myVec.end()} )
```

You can also declare an overload of `Method()` that takes the vector of derived pointers, for convenience, and just does this. This will prevent some code bloat when this is done frequently.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The overload does not really work for me, but the constructor-overload does. (The method belongs to a class which should not know about the derived objects.)

Comment: I'd also suggest overloading the function with a template that takes a pair of iterators